# extend default, options override everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

In my plugin I want to give full css controls. But some initial values has to be declared. To let users customize this initial values I'm calling a $.extend variable in which I pass all the inilial css.

As I try to override one or more part of that object, it will override EVERYTHING and not just what selected. Why?

I made I little fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Hfk79/ to be more clear:

Let's pretend this is my plugin:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function( options ) {
    var defaults = $.extend({
        pCSS : {
            color: 'red',
            margin: '1em'
        }
    }, options );

    var settings = $.extend( true, {}, defaults, options );

    return this.click(function() {
        $( this ).css( settings.pCSS );
    });
}
```

Users can now override default options.
And let's pretend I am an user who hate the red color and just want it to be blue and I feel OK with the other properties. I'd call the function passing this option:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '.plugin' ).myPlugin({
        pCSS: {
            color: 'blue'
        }
    });
});
```

HOWEVER this code will override EVERYTHING and not just the color!

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the first `extend` and getting rid of the `pCSS` inner object helps:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        color: 'red',
        margin: '1em'
    };

    var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);

    return this.click(function () {
        $(this).css(settings.pCSS);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.plugin').myPlugin({
        color: 'blue'
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hFLx3/14/)